# Using pastebin as a method to store login data

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a "simple" login script that will launch something else upon a correct login. Can I use Pastebin as a form of a text file? I want to be able to add and remove users from the list at any time and Pastebin lets me do this without setting up a whole MySQL database.

And I know this method is not super secure, but it's at least better than saving the data as a text file on the computer it's running from.

Here is a snippet of the current login system I'm using. It's a slightly edited "basic" login system that I found online, it had what I was looking for.

```
def Main():
    userName = input("\nUsername: ")+"\n"
    passWord = input("Password: ")
    with open("users.txt", 'r') as users:
        loginAndPass = users.readlines()
        if userName in loginAndPass:
            posi = loginAndPass.index(userName)
            if posi % 2 != 0:
                if testSHA512(passWord, loginAndPass[int(posi)+1].replace('\n', '')):
                    Good()
                else:
                    print("\nInvalid login or password\n")
            else:
                print("\nInvalid login or password\n")
        else:
            print("\nInvalid login or password\n")
```

As you can see its currently using `users.txt` as the file to check login data for, I would really like to be able to just save the data on Pastebin and be able to edit it whenever.

Comment: How is saving password data publicly in the internet "better" than saving it in a file on the local hard drive?

Comment: Anyway, Pastebin has an API which you can use.

Comment: @mkrieger1 The reason I want to use Pastebin instead of the file is so I'm able to edit the users to remove one or add more at any time, doing that with a file on the computer it's being run from is impossible. 

My main idea was to have one user everyone uses, and if there is a problem with the script I can remove the user making it impossible to log in.

I understand that this method is also not secure, but it still has more function then a text file on the computer.